# POWERSHELL Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s)

Tags: powershell, csv, ms-access

Need some help figuring out how to solve this issue:
Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "No value given for one or more required parameters."
At C:\Users\Dynamic\2.ps1:18 char:1

- $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OleDbException
  ```

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Dynamic\2.ps1:29 char:8

- while ($reader.Read()) {
- ```
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

```
$SalesOrder = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter Order'
$Item = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter Items'
$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Dynamic\DynamicCopy.accdb"
$conn.Open()

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
$cmd.Connection = $conn
#$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Dynamic WHERE SalesOrder = '$SalesOrder' AND Item = '$Item' ORDER BY ID ASC"
#$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
$cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Dynamic WHERE SalesOrder = ? AND Item = ? ORDER BY ID ASC"
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SalesOrder", $SalesOrder)
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", $Item)
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

$csvFile = "C:\Users\Dynamic\Dynamic.csv"
$csv = New-Object -ComObject "Scripting.FileSystemObject"
$csvStream = $csv.CreateTextFile($csvFile, $True)

$csvStream.WriteLine("ID,SalesOrder,Item")

while ($reader.Read()) {
    $csvStream.WriteLine("$($reader.GetValue(0)),$($reader.GetValue(1)),$($reader.GetValue(2))")
}

$csvStream.Close()

# Close Database Connection
$conn.Close()
```

Comment: Change the query to `"SELECT * FROM Dynamic WHERE SalesOrder = @SalesOrder AND Item = @Item ORDER BY ID ASC"`